# cannot retrieve data from firestore into listview flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve data from Firebase into the Listview.

this is my firebase cloud fire store [Image of Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JLKb.jpg)

i try many time with many ways and all codes doesn't any errors, but When i run the app and open the activity the data cannot show they will be empty,

here is my Code :

```
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {

Future _getTaxi() async {

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('taxi').get();
return querySnapshot.docs;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(


  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _getTaxi(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Card(


    child: ListTile(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
              
            Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
              Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["name"],     //taxi driver name
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25, 
                fontFamily: 'krmanj', 
              ),
            ),
              Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["line"],
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 20, 
                  fontFamily: 'krmanj', 
                ),
              ),
            ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),     
);
        });
    }
  }),
);
}
}
```

after run app and open the activity the Debug Console is showing this

```
Restarted application in 974ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 8359): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 8359): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 8359): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/Firestore( 8359): (22.1.2) [WatchStream]: (5cf536b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project bardarash-city., cause=null}.
W/Firestore( 8359): (22.1.2) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project bardarash-city., cause=null}
W/Firestore( 8359): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

Comment: This says your internet connection is not healthy at the moment, please make sure your connection is stable. Reason you are not getting data, is because you are not connecting to the cloud firestore due to bad internet connection.

Comment: My internet is very good i don't have any problem with internet in emulator

Answer (score 0):

After OP edit:
It says `permission denied`, you cannot connect to your firestore database. Double check your rules\permissions in Firebase console.

---

You have to use `data()`,

Like this:

```
 Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["name"]
 Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["line"]
```

Comment: What error do you get. Responding with `isn't solved` doesn't really help debugging.

Comment: Also, why are you ignoring `context` in `itemBuilder: (_,index)` ? What about trying `itemBuilder: (context , index)`

Comment: all things you told me i do it but the activity still empty.

Comment: Show the output of your debug console, could be a renderFlex error, how are you sure you are getting the data, but it's not being displayed?

Comment: see answer 2 i write it

Comment: I edited answer, double check firebase console rules, it says permission denied, this is an important error, worth mentioning.

Comment: the rule in firebase is allow read, write : if true;

Comment: perhaps you could temporarily try deleting/disabling the firebase rules to test is there is any that could be causing trouble? Also trying to connect from another internet source to test the function could be worth a try.
I have also heard of other who Try to uninstall app from android emulator and rebuild could help resolve the issue, have you tried that?

Comment: i will try it too.